# Display attached images only for current post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, post

I want to display my post text and images separately, like in two different columns.

I followed dew tricks found online. Unfortunatly, they work but not the way I want them to. It's displaying all the images present in media instead of the images which I inserted in the current post. I found the following snippet in almost every solution related to this topic.

Code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID );
$attachments = get_post($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">';
the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , flase );
echo '</div>';
}
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$images = get_attached_media('image');
```

You can then use your existing foreach loop

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But unfortunately that didn't do the trick. May be I am making some mistake. :( .So I am dropping the idea for now, but will be open to any more suggestions.